# Open new tab html mvc

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to **open a new tab** as long as certain **conditions are met**. To do this, I understand that `target="_blank`" is used in the `html form`, the problem with this is that they will open regardless of whether or not the condition is met. How can I make it happen only when the condition is met?

This is my `ActionResult` with which **I control the conditions**:

```
public ActionResult ChAzul(double? titulo)
{
    ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
    var suscriptor = cn.cargarDatos(Convert.ToDouble(titulo));
    var caracteres = Convert.ToString(titulo).Length;
    string uname = string.Empty;
    if (Session["uname"] != null)
    {
        uname = Convert.ToString(Session["uname"]);
    }
    var usuario = cn.datosCob(uname);
    if (uname == string.Empty)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else if (usuario[0].conectado == false)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else if (caracteres <= 3 || caracteres > 6)
    {
        ViewBag.Alert = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 4 (cuatro) ni mayor a 6 (seis).";
        return View("Cuotas", usuario);
    }
    else if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, este título no existe.";
        return View("Cuotas", usuario);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ChAzul", suscriptor);
    }
}
```

Only in this line `return View("ChAzul", suscriptor);` is when the new tab should open, how can I achieve it?

This is my view for what it's worth:

```
    <form id="frmCU" method="post" action="@Url.Action("ChAzul", "Home")">
        <label for="titulo">Título: </label>
        <input type="number" id="titulo" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="titulo" maxlength="6" placeholder="Ingrese su título..." required
               title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 4. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 5"
               onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
        @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
        {
            <div class="alert">
                <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                <strong>Providus informa: </strong>
                <p id="textoAlerta">@ViewBag.Alert</p>
            </div>
        }
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking cannot be done from within the `Controller` itself.

You need it do this on from your `View`. For this you can apply the `target` attribute on your `form` while posting to your `Controller`.

Now you have already mentioned that you do not want this to happen but rather you want it to happen on a condition inside your `Controller`:

```
<form id="frmCU" method="post" action="@Url.Action("ChAzul", "Home")" target="_blank">
```

So in order to do this, you can use `AJAX` to get a response from from your `Controller` method and based on that, you can redirect to your `ChAzul` view in a new tab . In simplest terms, your call would something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/ChAzul',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        titulo: 1
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.status=="true")
      {
        var urlToRedirect= '@Url.Action("ChAzul","Home")';
        window.location.href = urlToRedirect; //Redirect here
      }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('fail');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

And your `Controller` will look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ChAzul(double? titulo)
{
    //Your logic here

    return Json(new {status="true", msg= "Successful authentication"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: i understand, but what about the return view inside conditions? what happen with that?

Comment: @FrancoJoelBalsamo Where you put your `return View` conditions, you need to send the conditions back to your `View` via `AJAX` call. Inside the `success` function of your `AJAX` call, you will determine which logic will redirect to which `View`. This logic will come from your `Controller` method. You will return back a `JSON` object to your `View` which shall be processed and then redirected as per your logic.

Comment: okay, thanks for your time & answer